# How to move a wire in Node-RED from one node to another?

Tags: node-red

Imagine I have wired a flow as follows:

[image]

and now wish to rewire to:

[image]

It seems that my option is to delete the existing wires and then re-wire them.  My question is:

---

**Question**

Is it possible to *move* wires from one node to another as opposed to deletion and recreation?

---

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hold down shift while dragging from the end of the wire you want to move

Comment: Worked perfectly.   I hunted hard for that.   Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: It was only added in the 0.13 release and was included in the accompanying blog post. Not the full documentation we ought to have, but something.